# Python SeleniumExtract href containing specific strings

Tags: python, selenium

I am using python selenium to capture source code

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
source_code = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
```

I need to extract element from the source code that contains a keyword like - jam, honey, choc and print to file named recipes.txt  for example

/items/John-string-jam-string.html

These are examples of the format of the href values

```
<a href="/items/John-string-jam-string.html"
<a href="/items/Paul-string-string-jam-string.html"
<a href="/items/string-Mary-honey-string.html"
<a href="/items/choc-string-string.html"
```

There are numerous other `<a href =/items/` that contain no reference to my key words which I do not want.

I am new to python and selenium but I am enjoying challenge. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve it. For instance, using the XPath locator and [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains):

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'jam') or contains(@href, 'honey') or contains(@href, 'choc')]")
```

Or, with a CSS selector and `*=` notation:

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*=jam],a[href*=honey],a[href*=choc]")
```

---

If you do not want to "hardcode" the search word values inside the expressions, you can dynamically construct your locator:

```
words = ["jam", "honey", "choc"]
condition = " or ".join("contains(@href, '%s')" % word for word in words)
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[%s]" % condition)
```

---

To extract/print out the actual `href` attribute values, use [`.get_attribute()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute):

```
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: The first suggestion is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks.